# Angular testing: How to get elementRef of ViewChildren

Tags: angular, jasmine

I want to write a unit test to check if my function sets the border of `mat-card`'s correctly. I grab the card using `ViewChildren`.

So in my test, I am trying to mock the `QueryList<ElementRef>` and pass it to `component.cards`. I know that I can get the `elementRef` of the `fixture`, but how do I specifically get the `elementRef` of the `mat-card`'s

Do I need to mock the `mat-card` component somehow?

```
@ViewChildren(MatCard, { read: ElementRef }) cards: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  public setCardBorder(i: number, color?: string) {
    this.cards.toArray()[i].nativeElement.style.border = `solid 1px ${color || 'var(--color-background-secondary)'}`;
  }
```

```
  it('setCardBorder should update border', () => {
    const mockCards = new QueryList();
    // I want to get the elementRef of the cards instead
    mockCards.reset([fixture.elementRef]);
    component.cards = mockCards as any;

    component.setCardBorder(0, 'var(--color-black)');

    expect(fixture.nativeElement.style.border).toBe('solid 1px var(--color-black)'');
  });
```

```
    <div *ngFor="let callToAction of callToActions; let i = index;">
        <mat-card class="card"
                  (mouseover)="setCardBorder(i, callToAction.color)"
                  (mouseout)="setCardBorder(i)">
        </mat-card>
    </div>
```